# Visual Studio debugging VB.Net Web Forms App shows Locals as Busy... then hangs

Tags: vb.net, debugging, webforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to debug a Web Forms application written in VB.Net and Visual Studio (2017) keeps hanging as soon as I try to move through a breakpoint.

The Locals window shows "Busy..." and is never populated with any variables (see image).

Debugging an MVC application works.

I've tried updating VS to the latest version, running in Safe Mode, removing the bin and obj directories, and rebooting; all to no avail.

I've also pulled the code into a new local repository from the current working version in TFS and it crashes in the same place.

Am I missing something obvious or is a re-install the next step?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to create new blank VB.Net Web Forms App to check if it still have this issue? If not, this issue should be related to your project, you can try to create a new VB.Net Web Forms App and copy code to it. If yes, it should more related to your VS, you can try to delete .vs folder or re-install VS.

Comment: MS team released a new VS version 15.8.4 yesterday, you can update your Visual Studio to latest version to check if it helps.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thanks for trying. I ended up re-installing as nothing seemed to work and I couldn't find reference to the same problem elsewhere. Frustrating but not worth spending too long trying to fix when there's work to be done...

Comment: some other users also reported similar issue here, you can check when you free :), https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312911/1580-debug-freezes.html

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I've just had this issue occur again in an MVC application. I've tried updating to 15.8.6 but the only change is that the "Busy..." doesn't appear when VS crashes. There doesn't appear to be a solution on the link you've posted. If I start on the Watch window it seems to let me move onto Locals but won't start there.